# Solving an equation with power (p-q) where p>q

Tags: linear-algebra

$\frac{\{(k-a)(k-b)(k-c).....(k-y)(k-z)\}^{(p-q)}}{(abcd.....xyz)^{(q-p)}}$

Here, $p>q$

Comment: Welcome to the website. Please try to give some context and explain what you have tried!

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{\{(k-a)(k-b)(k-c).....(k-y)(k-z)\}^{(p-q)}}{(abcd.....xyz)^{(q-p)}}$

$=\frac{\{(k-a).....(k-k).....(k-z)\}^{(p-q)}}{(abcd.....xyz)^{(q-p)}}$

$=\frac{\{0\}^{(p-q)}}{(abcd.....xyz)^{(q-p)}}$

$=0$ $[p>q]$

So, the value is $0$.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Ok, I understand